# vertically aligned divs on opposite sides of page

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

We're embedding a stripped-down version of our web app in a third party page as an iframe. 
I'd like to have a bottom "toolbar", containing 2 links, one of which is plain text, and the other our company logo prefaced by text. I'd like the two links to be in the opposite corners, and vertically aligned to the middle of the containing toolbar div. Using [this approach](https://willkoehler.net/2014/08/28/vertically-align-content-with-css-using-this-one-weird-trick.html) here's what I've got so far [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwold/kbjycez2/) :

```
<div id="main-app"></div>

<div id="my-footer">
  <span id="full-link" class="assert-position"><a href="https://url.to.webapp" target="_blank" class="assert-position">View full size</a> </span> <div id="filler" class="assert-position"></div> Powered by
  <a href="http://www.company-landing-page.co.uk" target="_blank" class="assert-position"> <img src="/images/my-company_logo.png"/></a>
</div>
<style>
     *{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }

      #main-app {
          height: 90%;
          width: 100%;
      }

      #my-footer {
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0f0f0f;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, "sans-serif"
      }

      #full-link {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, "sans-serif";
        font-size: small;
        color: #FFF;
      }

      #filler {
        height: 100%;
      }

      #my-footer img{

        margin: 3px;
      }

      .assert-position{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      #full-link a:visited{
        color: #FFF
       }
</style>
```

The problem is that everything I do to try and get the link on the left vertically aligned properly (as the text is with the image) either does nothing, or destroys the horizontal alignment. Because I don't control or even know how big the embedded iframe is going to be, anything in terms of a fixed number of pixels (say using position: absolute) is right out.
I'm sure this should be easy, but as a backend dev at heart I'm tearing my hair out over it. Also, I'd prefer to avoid using any third party libraries such as bootstrap, as my main app isn't using them and I don't want any global settings from my existing dependencies getting overriden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kbjycez2/68/

To vertically align your links to the middle, you need to provide line-height to your **#my-footer** element.

I've used flex model to align your links to the left and right.

The following snippet might work for you:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#main-app {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}

#my-footer {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, "sans-serif";
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: calc(10vh);
}

#my-footer img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#full-link a:visited {
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<div id="main-app"></div>

<div id="my-footer">
  <div>
    <a href="https://url.to.webapp">View Full Size</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Powered By </span>
    <a href="http://www.company-landing-page.co.uk"><img src="/images/my-company_logo.png" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment is a pain. That technique explained in the link strikes me as a tad complicated.

What I do is I have a div that is absolutely positioned, with these values:

```
{
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

To make this work, the my-footer must have `position:relative`.

This has the advantage of not requiring a "filler" div or anything like that. In the solution I'm showing here, I've made a class "vAlign" which has the above attributes, then I just added "left:5px" and "right:5px" in the css for each footer element (I created "company-link" id for the 'Powered by' part), eliminating the need for float. I also increased the height of the footer to make the vertical align more obvious.

```css
     *{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }

      #main-app {
          height: 70%;
          width: 100%;
      }

      #my-footer {
        position:relative;
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0f0f0f;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, "sans-serif"
      }

      #full-link {
        left:5px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, "sans-serif";
        font-size: small;
        color: #FFF;
      }

      #filler {
        height: 100%;
      }

      #my-footer img{

        margin: 3px;
      }

      #full-link a:visited{
        color: #FFF
       }
       
      #companyLink {
        right:5px;
      }
       
      .v-align {
         position:absolute;
         top:50%;
         transform:translateY(-50%);
      }
```

```html
<div id="main-app"></div>

<div id="my-footer">

  <div id="full-link" class="v-align"><a href="https://url.to.webapp" target="_blank" class="assert-position">View full size</a> </div>
  
  <div id="companyLink" class="v-align">Powered by <a href="http://www.company-landing-page.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="/images/my-company_logo.png"/></a><div>
  
</div>
```